# margin-right is not working with my HTML. How can I center my content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Recently, I am learning **Responsive Design**.  But I've got some trouble in centering my content when the screen gets big.

Here is the problem:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    body {
        margin: 10%;
    }
}
```

When I set the margin to 10%, only the `margin-top` and `margin-left` work.  This is not what I want.  `margin-right` doesn't work at all.

Here is the picture:

[image: the picture]

So, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 13):

This is happening, because you are not setting the width of the body properly. If you specify margins, then you see `margin-left` working and it pushes your content to the right out of the screen.

You need to sum up the width and margins to 100%, so by giving 10% margins on both sides, you have to adjust the width to 80%.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    html {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 10%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't always have to adjust the calculation. You can also set them to auto-adjust like this:

```
body {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your content you can also use the `position: relative;` property of CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
body {
 position: relative;
 top: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 right: 10%;
 left: 0%;
 }
}
```

you can also give values in pixels like `50px;`

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is your short and sweet answer**

```css
 body{margin: 0;}
.wrapper{width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;}
.wrapper img{max-width: 100%}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://images3.alphacoders.com/278/27807.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline level elements by default. You need to use display:block; if you want your images and margin to work properly.

`img
{
 display: block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Making the parent div style "float: right;" fixed this for me. In the parent I only had the content that needed to position.