# css margin not applying for this right side

Tags: html, css

I want to apply padding to the right of this input field but its not working this is how it look like I want to add a margin like on the left side to the right side
[image: This is the how it look like after style and the right margin is not displaying]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: solid #5f9341 1px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #5f9341;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button id="save">Save input</button>
  <button id="save">Save input</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can we see you html too?

Comment: please add appropriate HTML and CSS code, as right now, we have no HTML to view what is going on, and your CSS is cut off at the beginning.

You should also use Stack Overflow's built in "Live Preview" feature to demonstrate your code through the browser, and not a screenshot.

Comment: we don't see your fully CSS

Comment: I have add the HTML and this is the full css

Comment: `margin` **adds** width/height to the element, that's why you're not seeing it work and also creating the horizontal scroll. What you could do for the `input` is set the width to `width: calc(100%-10px)` to get the desired effect. Or add a wrapping element around the input to add padding to the right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [margin-right is not working with my HTML. How can I center my content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405576/margin-right-is-not-working-with-my-html-how-can-i-center-my-content)

Answer (score 2):

`margin` **adds** width/height to the element, that's why you're not seeing it work and also creating the horizontal scroll. What you could do for the input is set the width to `width: calc(100% - 10px)` to get the desired effect. Or add a wrapping element around the input to add padding to the right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid #5f9341 1px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #5f9341;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="not wrapped" />
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" id="input-wrapped" placeholder="wrapped" />
  </div>
  <button id="save">Save input</button>
  <button id="save">Save input</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I think it should be `(100% - 2* 10px)` for left and right margin

Comment: @Cédric doesn't need the left margin, since the body padding does that. Also,  `2*10px` would just make the input 20px less and be 10px short on the right side.

Comment: We probably understood a different need, I'm guessing the OP wants its div to be centered with some left and right space

Comment: @Cédric yeah, the OP could definitely be more clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your margin is working but you set the input `width: 100%` so your div is larger than the body.

You can use `calc()` to fit your div in its container

```css
:root {
  --input-margin: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--input-margin));
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: var(--input-margin);
  margin-left: var(--input-margin);
  margin-right: var(--input-margin);
  border: solid #5f9341 1px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #5f9341;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#save:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="save">Save input</button>
<button id="save">Save input</button>
```